# Fetching data from the Wiki

Tags: python, mediawiki

I am currently developing a wiki and will keep posting information into the wiki. However, I'll have to fetch the information from the wiki using a python code. For example, if I have a wiki page about a company, say Coca Cola, I will need all the information (text) that I have posted on the wiki to be parsed to my python program. Please let me know if there's a way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A manner is to download the page with urllib or httplib, then to analyze it with regexes to extract the precise information you want. It may be long, but it's relatively easy to do.

Maybe there are other solutions to analyze the source of the page, parsers or something like that; I don't know enough about them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [api.php](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) to get the Wikipedia Source text. It includes only the actual article.

I have written this one for the german wikipedia, so it works with umlauts. Some special characters of some other languages don't work (russian works, so it might be some asian languages). This is a working example:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
import xml.sax.saxutils

def load(lemma, language="en", format="xml"):
    """ Get the Wikipedia Source Text (not the HTML source code) 

        format:xml,json, ...
        language:en, de, ...

        Returns None if page doesn't exist
    """
    url       = 'http://' + language + '.wikipedia.org/w/api.php' + \
                '?action=query&format=' + format + \
                '&prop=revisions&rvprop=content' + \
                '&titles=' + lemma
    request   = urllib2.Request(url)
    handle    = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    text      = handle.read()
    if format == 'xml':
        soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(text)
        rev  = soup.rev
        if rev != None:
            text = unicode(rev.contents[0])
            text = xml.sax.saxutils.unescape(text)
        else:
            return None
    return text

print load("Coca-Cola")
```

If you like to get the actual source code you have to change the url and the part with BeautifulStoneSoup.

BeautifulStoneSoup parses XML, BeautifulSoup parses HTML. Both are part of [the BeautifulSoup package](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the past for this sort of thing I've used [SemanticMediawiki](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki), and found it to work reasonably well. It's not terribly flexible, though so if you're doing something complicated you'll find yourself writing custom plugins or delegating to an external service to do the work.

I ultimately ended up writing a lot of python web services to do extra processing.

Answer (score 0):

--> Retrieve data from the Wikipedia API for a given article title

```
function fetchWikiData($a){ 
  $URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=" . urlencode($a) . "&rvprop=content&origin=*";
  $response = file_get_contents($URL); return $response 
}
```

I am not the author of this function.
Regards,